# Python set datetime hour to be a specific time

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to get the date to be yesterday at 11.30 PM.

Here is my code:

```
    import datetime
    yesterday = datetime.date.today () - datetime.timedelta (days=1) 
    PERIOD=yesterday.strftime ('%Y-%m-%d') 
    new_period=PERIOD.replace(hour=23, minute=30)
    print new_period
```

however i am getting this error:

```
TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

First, change `datetime.date.today()` to `datetime.datetime.today()` so that you can manipulate the time of the day.

Then call `replace` before turning the time into a string.

So instead of:

```
PERIOD=yesterday.strftime ('%Y-%m-%d') 
new_period=PERIOD.replace(hour=23, minute=30)
```

Do this:

```
new_period=yesterday.replace(hour=23, minute=30).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print new_period
```

Also keep in mind that the string you're converting it to displays no information about the hour or minute. If you're interested in that, add `%H` for hour and `%M` for the minute information to your format string.

Comment: i get this error: `'hour' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: Fixed, just realized the author was using `datetime.date` instead of `datetime.datetime`. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 20):

You can use datetime.combine(date, time, tzinfo=self.tzinfo)

```
import datetime
yesterday = datetime.date.today () - datetime.timedelta (days=1)
t = datetime.time(hour=23, minute=30)
print(datetime.datetime.combine(yesterday, t))
```

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want?

```
from datetime import datetime
yesterday = datetime(2014, 5, 12, 23, 30)
print yesterday
```

*Edited*

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

diff = 60 * 60 * 24

yesterday = datetime(*datetime.fromtimestamp(calendar.timegm(datetime.today().utctimetuple()) - diff).utctimetuple()[:3], hour=23, minute=30)

print yesterday
```

Comment: Tomorrow this will refer to two days before, not yesterday. It gets more and more inaccurate with each passing day.

Comment: I should have edited it to 
    yesterday = datetime(2014, 5, 13, 23, 30)
 in the next day : )

Comment: You should edit the answer every day to keep it current. Maybe use Selenium and then have a cron job run everyday to edit your answer. That would be awesome.

Comment: I'll try with requests and beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 0):

In one line, here you go

```
import datetime

new_period=(datetime.datetime.today()- datetime.timedelta (days=1)).replace(hour=23, minute=30)
```