# How to create a epoch timestamp in milliseconds each day using python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a small epoch function which would end up giving me a resulting time stamp of the following format :

`1501149934.372957`

[image]

I am trying to do something as follows :

```
def create_slack_timestamp():
    start_time = '4:00'
    end_time = '5:00'

    date=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

    create_epoch = date + start_time
```

I am intersted in generating the epoch time specifically at 4:00PM and 5:00PM .
How can i achieve this ?

Comment: this is so wrong in so many levels. first of all `4:00` certainly isn't `4:00 PM` but `AM` if written so. You need to create the timestamp for the given hour, so presumably you'd have to create a new datetime with changed time of day; then you can get the epoch timestamp with `timestamp()` ... i.e. `datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()`.

Comment: i apologize , but i hope the question made sense. how can achive something like this , the timestamp() function ?

Comment: Specifically the epoch time at 4:00 PM and 5:00 PM on *this* day, in your local timezone? Even that's not clear from your question.

Comment: [Adapt from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642676/python-set-datetime-hour-to-be-a-specific-time) - then `.timestamp()`